# How to disable specific hours in specific dates in Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker?

Tags: datepicker, datetimepicker

I am using [Bootstrap 3 DateTimePicker](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker) and I am trying to disable some specific hours in some specific dates. For example, I want to disable 08:00 hour option in 06/27/2018 and 17:00 hour option in 06/30/2018.

I tried to use "disabledHours" option. But this option disables the given hour in all days.

So how can I achieve this?

Here are my codes.

```
$(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD hh:ii',
    datesDisabled: ['2016/08/20'],
    autoclose: true,    
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no in-built functions to disable specific hours in a specific date. But the case can be achieved by using the `onRenderHour` method. Store the hours to be disabled in specific dates in the array `disabledtimes_mapping`. Those will be disabled automatically while rendering the picker.

P.S: This date-picker is deprecated. The same is forked and maintained by [AuspeXeu](https://github.com/AuspeXeu/bootstrap-datetimepicker) in GitHub.

```js
var disabledtimes_mapping = ["06/27/2018:8", "06/30/2018:17", "06/30/2018:15"];

function formatDate(datestr)
{
    var date = new Date(datestr);
    var day = date.getDate(); day = day>9?day:"0"+day;
    var month = date.getMonth()+1; month = month>9?month:"0"+month;
    return month+"/"+day+"/"+date.getFullYear();
}

$(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD hh:ii',
    datesDisabled: ['2018-06-20'],
    autoclose: true,
    onRenderHour:function(date){
  if(disabledtimes_mapping.indexOf(formatDate(date)+":"+date.getUTCHours())>-1)
    {
        return ['disabled'];
    }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/AuspeXeu/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/AuspeXeu/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input class="datepicker" type="text">
```

Comment: You are my hero. Thanks you so much :)